# How to mint Solana NFT?

Tags: solana-program, nft, api

Is there any API I can use which can be used without the need for onchain programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple tooling options to get this data. I like to use Crossmint NFT Mint API Add-on on QuickNode Marketplace as it let's me use all the other blockchain tools under one dashboard.

Here's a JavaScript example:

```
                    const axios = require("axios");
(() => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const data = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "cm_mintNFT",
    params: ["FILL_ME_ARG_1", "FILL_ME_ARG_2", "FILL_ME_ARG_3"],
  };
  axios
    .post(
      "https://FILL_YOUR_ENDPOINT_HERE.com",
      data,
      config
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(err);
    });
})();
```

Check the different RPCs and examples in various languages here --> https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/nft-mint-api-mainnet/

Answer (score 2):

there is multiple solutions for this.

For example the https://studio.metaplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options available. You can use no-code solutions like [Underdog Protocol](https://underdogprotocol.com/) or [Crossmint](https://www.crossmint.com/). Or use Metaplex's [Candy Machine](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/getting-started) JS SDK to do it programmatically.